# How to unify pl/sql packages

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I have two different packages with the same procedures (number and names), but overloaded. In the second package each procedure has one more parameter.

Specifically, in one procedure there are different declarations (cursors, etc), but EXACTLY the same code.

Now, I would like to have that code in one place, so as to maintain it in a single place. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can have the overloaded procedures in the same package. But if you are asking whether you can have just one procedure rather than replicate the code, the answer is also yes, you can have one procedure with all the parameters, and then check the value of them within the procedure. You can also set a DEFAULT value for each parameter should someone call the procedure without all the require parameters (although this does assume an certain order for the parameters)

Comment: Hi Dave, 
What I actually need is to use the same code for different cursors, that fetch records from different tables and with different conditions.

Comment: then it sounds like you need different procedures, but you can put them in the same package to make things a bit tidier for you